# Does crop factor affect light meter readings?

Tags: film, crop-factor, light-meter

I was reading about crop factors that for example a Polaroid land camera on `f/3.2` lens is something around `f/1.4` equivalent in `35mm` film including the crop factor.  ( Until now I was under impression that crop factor only affect the focal point ).

So does that mean when I am measuring with a light meter, should I convert the f number too depending on the crop factor and use that new value for the light meter readings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does sensor size affect the brightness of an image given the same field of view and aperture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65193/how-does-sensor-size-affect-the-brightness-of-an-image-given-the-same-field-of-v)

Comment: How many times are we going to do this same question?

Comment: There's no such thing as true *equivalence*. With regard to f-number, crop factor applies to DoF, but not to exposure. Related: [Confused about T-stop number. Does it account for crop factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94518/15871) and [Can I emulate a fullframe sensor with angular lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95168/15871) and [How to achieve full-frame look/view on a crop-sensor - without changing the lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73325/15871)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about T-stop number. Does it account for crop factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94518/confused-about-t-stop-number-does-it-account-for-crop-factor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the light meter reading (for example, ISO 100, f/11, 1/200 second) already applies to any camera, any sensor size, any crop factor.  That''s the beauty of the "f/stop" numbering system.

Crop factor might apply to focal length and sensor size situations, but Not to exposure.

Answer (score 1):

No correction is needed. The image formed by the lens is still that of a lens of the nominal focal length. You can use a lens designed for a full frame body on a cropped-frame body, but the image formed by the lens won't change because you put a body with a smaller sensor behind it.
What changes is the part of the image that is used: a sensor smaller than 24×36 mm only uses the center of the image, and thus has a field of view that is smaller than for a full-frame (24×36 mm) sensor. The crop factor expresses this, and only this.